# What does "as e " mean in "rospy.ServiceException as e"

Tags: service, ros, rospy

when I tried to have ROS exception handling, I came across with following syntax and I am unable to identify the significance of `as e` in the syntax of

```
rospy.ServiceException as e
```

is `e some kind of variable to store the error or something else?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement, https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: It is alias to make your code simple.

Answer (score 2):

In the context of rospy.ServiceException as e, as e is a way to give a short name (e in this case) to the exception object that will be raised if an error occurs.

Let's break it down:

rospy: This refers to the rospy module in ROS (Robot Operating System), which is a popular robotics middleware framework for building robotic systems.

ServiceException: This is an exception class within the rospy module that is raised when there's an issue related to a service call in ROS. For example, if a service request fails or if there's a problem with the service server, a rospy.ServiceException might be raised.

as e: This part is an aliasing statement. By writing as e, you're creating an alias or shorthand for the rospy.ServiceException instance that will be raised in case of an exception. Using e as the alias is a common convention, but you can choose any other valid variable name.